# wo network cards. How to setup one lan and one wan on server

Tags: linux, networking, centos, lan, wan

I  have a server with two NIC cards. Right now eth0 is connected to my router to my ISP. But i want to setup eth1 as my LAN so deliver an internet connection from the server to my laptop.

How can i setup my eth1 as a LAN while my eth0 is a WAN.

I am running CENTOS 6.4 terminal.

Answer (score 0):

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forwarding`

will enable IP forwarding.  You need to put this in a startup script for it to persist after boot.  You can also set this kernel setting in `sysctl.conf` (wherever it is on CentOS).

You also need to look into `iptables` to set up some basic security, as well as NAT if you need it.

Comment: Its not working I tried making settings in the eth0 and eth1

Comment: Try flushing all iptables rules http://www.adminsehow.com/2009/08/how-to-clear-all-iptables-rules/

Also make sure all machines behind this one have a static IP in the same subnet as your eth1, or you could install and configure a DHCP server such as `isc-dhcp-server` or `udhcpd` on this system.